# IoC-Like-Codegeneration (T4?)

Tags: c#, plugins, inversion-of-control, t4

This request might sounds a little bit odd, but application-performance and maintenance is cruciual, so I'm really looking for something as described.

Because I'm not sure if the 3 words are enough to explain what I'm looking for, here's an example:

I use IoC a lot, especially if I have dyniamical behaviours, which is often the case.
It's a very easy and frankly cool technique to have a loose coupled application.

But the freedom comes with a price of a higher performance-cost, compared with a "hard wired" solution.
Normally this is not a too big issue, but in the current case, it is.

So what I'd like to have is a feature which works like an IoC, but of course with a hard-wired .cs-file, instead of an "generated at runtime" Container.
Like if I need all implementations of IBehaviour, I'd get an output such as "behaviours = new List { impl1, impl2, ... }, instead of behaviours = Container.GetAllInstancesOf()

Hope it's clear what I'm looking for and that something like this exists.
And if not: What would be the way to implement this feature? Only way I can imagine is a VisualStudio-Plugin which reflects a compiled dll and with the help of custom attributes can  write a .t4-file.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you're looking for exists, but I implemented something which may serve as an example to get you started: a T4 typed factory generator. Basically you mark your class with an attribute and T4 will generate a factory implementation based on a factory interface (if it doesn't exist, the script will generate the factory interface as well).

You can look at the code at https://github.com/PombeirP/T4Factories, and a NuGet package is available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4Factories/.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for the link.
I think it's a good starting-point indeed and the project itself is also very cool. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that ioc has:

> higher performance-cost, compared with a "hard wired" solution

?

Comparing the [performance](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison), you can see that:

- singleton registration takes **68ms**, without container **78ms**
- transient (a new instance is created every time) takes  **66ms**, without container **88ms**

Moreover, now IoC container is very small, for example DryIoc has no more than 2500 lines of code including comments.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I did some benchmarks, but not as detailed as in this blog-post. Maybe I have to give it another go, or maybe I should have to change my IoC-container (although StructureMap should be a very good one...)

Answer (score 0):

#### Update:

[DryIocZero](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIocZero) supports compile-time generation of factories with all registered dependencies (I am a maintainer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a compile time IOC container for .Net which should have almost zero overhead (for many cases it generates practically the same code as you would write yourself). Try it out at https://github.com/YairHalberstadt/stronginject.